# Редирект со страниц с цифрами в конце htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

Добрый день! Подскажите, возможно ли сделать редирект для всех страниц, которые содержат цифры в конце на такой же урл без цифр?
Пример:

```
/mezhdunarodnaya-dostavka/rossiya/alekseevskaya-10576/
```

перенаправить на

```
/mezhdunarodnaya-dostavka/rossiya/alekseevskaya/
```

Буду благодарен если кто подскажет с решением или заготовкой htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)\-\d+/$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Спасибо! Вопрос решен!